# onload function in javascript not working Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to read a image as a file and then display the image name,size etc. I debugged my code and found my onload function is loading but not working. Thank you for your help. I have included my whole FileSelection() method.

```
var iBytesUploaded = 0;
var iBytesTotal = 0;
var iPreviousBytesLoaded = 0;
var iMaxFilesize = 1048576; // 1MB
var oTimer = 0;
var sResultFileSize = '';
var oImage = new Image();


function fileSelected() {

alert("hello");
// hide different warnings

document.getElementById('upload_response').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('error2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'none';

// get selected file element
var oFile = document.getElementById('image_file').files[0];

// filter for image files
var rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
    alert("problem");
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
    return;
}

// little test for filesize
if (oFile.size > iMaxFilesize) {
    document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'block';
    return;
}

// get preview element
    oImage = document.getElementById('preview');
    alert("hello2");


// prepare HTML5 FileReader
var oReader = new FileReader();

    alert("hello3")

    oReader.onload = function(e)
    {
       alert("hello4");


    alert("reached");

    oImage.onload = function () { // binding onload event

        alert("hi");

       // oImage.src = e.target.result;
        // we are going to display some custom image information here

        sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
        document.getElementById('fileinfo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + oFile.name;
        document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + sResultFileSize;
        document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + oFile.type;
        document.getElementById('filedim').innerHTML = 'Dimension: ' + oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight;
    };

     // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we will use as a source of the image
    oImage.src = e.target.result;
};

 alert("file found");
// read selected file as DataURL
oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
```

}

Comment: Not sure if it's the root of the error, but you never defined oImage as a variable.

Comment: the variable is already defined in the starting of code. I have pasted only a small function not the full code. Sorry,my bad

Comment: So is it oImage.onload that's not firing or oReader.onload that's not firing? Or do you mean the code inside the functions are not working.

Comment: oImage.src is not firing...... My code is working till alert("hello4");

Comment: what type of variable is oImage?

Comment: Oh wait I see the problem. You need put oImage.src = e.target.result AFTER the oImage.onload function.

Comment: var oImage;    This is how i have declared the variable. I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: you'd want to have var oImage = new Image();

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I did try your solution but it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you post new code to see the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving you the changes I was talking about in the comments:

```
//You want this somewhere
var oImage = new Image();

var oReader = new FileReader();

alert("hello3")

oReader.onload = function(e)
{
   alert("hello4");
   oImage.onload = function () { // binding onload event
      alert("hi");
      // we are going to display some custom image information here
      sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
      document.getElementById('fileinfo').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + oFile.name;
      document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + sResultFileSize;
      document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + oFile.type;
      document.getElementById('filedim').innerHTML = 'Dimension: ' + oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight;
     };

     // Make sure this comes after
     oImage.src = e.target.result;
};

// read selected file as DataURL
oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
```

Comment: I did exactly as you asked, but still my onload function is not firing.

Comment: Hmm... can you console.log e.target.result to make sure it's actually a data url? Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: My console does not report any error. I will share my whole js file. May i have ur email or should i share here ??

Comment: share it here, others may help too

Comment: I edited my question above and shared my whole method.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you console.log e.target.result and tell me what you get? The only thing I can think of right now is that you aren't loading a proper url in oImage.src so nothing ever loads.

Comment: Same thing I am thinking but my logcat doesn't reveal any error.  My console message  - 2-01 15:03:54.827 15218-15218/com.example.ac046137.webviewcamera V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.webkit.WebView{41d49920 VFEDHVC. .F...... 0,0-600,951} softInputMode=16 first=false flags=#1810100

Comment: if that's what you are getting from loggin e.target.result then it's definitely the fact that you aren't getting a proper url from filereader

Comment: Can I email you my html and js file. Its too big to share here.

Comment: I don't think it's your code, but whatever you are inputing as the file to be read. Try setting oImage.src to an actual image url (like http://i.stack.imgur.com/3H7nS.png) and see if you get a reaction.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I changed the code totally and got the result. Thank you for your help